# Do you need a seperate pair of AWS keys for each S3 Bucket?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, ruby-on-rails-4, aws-sdk

OR can I use the same one pair, for let's say 3 buckets (dev, production, staging).

Please advise!

Answer (score 3):

You can certainly use a single set of AWS credentials to manage multiple S3 buckets.

Or, you can set it up so that each bucket requires different AWS credentials.

Or, you can configure the access so that you use an IAM instance role from an EC2 instance our instances without having to create and manage individual keys.

Or, you can grant access to users in other AWS accounts to assume roles to manage S3 buckets in your account.

Or, you can use Amazon Cognito so that individual users can log in with their own personal accounts on Amazon, Facebook, Google, or any OpenID Connect-compatible identity provider, and then create and manage their own objects in your S3 buckets without stepping on each other's toes.

Or, ...

[Please submit each "how" as a separate, new question.]

Answer (score 0):

You can do either.  It depends on how you setup the policy associated with the user (or group).  I would recommend a different set of keys for each environment, in case one environment is compromised and to prevent accidental overwrites.

Here's a policy that matches the user name to the bucket name:

```
{
   "Version":"2012-10-17",
   "Statement":[
      {
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Action":[
            "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
         ],
         "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::*"
      },
      {
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Action":[
            "s3:ListBucket",
            "s3:GetBucketLocation"
         ],
         "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::${aws:username}"
      },
      {
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Action":[
            "s3:PutObject",
            "s3:PutObjectAcl",
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:GetObjectAcl",
            "s3:DeleteObject",
            "s3:DeleteObjectAcl"
         ],
         "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::${aws:username}/*"
      }
   ]
}
```

You can then generate dev, staging, and production IAM users.  Give them the same name as the buckets.  Each will be given a different key + secret.  When your app tries to access the bucket it will confirm that the key and secret are correct for the environment-specific bucket.

Answer (score 0):

Though this question is old, and you may have resolved your issue by now. 
I am writing this answer for future readers.

You can use same bucket for all environments. However you should use different buckets. 
**Reason:** assets gets uploaded on same bucket with all environments may get ID conflicts between them. Sooner or later you will face this problem. So its better to be fail safe.

In Heroku you can setup separate config for multiple environments. In your case `dev` `production` and `staging` (I am assuming you have set these references with above names, or if you haven't and trying to add staging environment to existing app, you may refer to [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/multiple-environments#starting-from-an-existing-app) or if starting from scratch thn [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/multiple-environments#starting-from-scratch)).

you might be having your config something like (It has config related to Paperclip)

```
has_attached_file :photo, 
  :styles => ...,
  :path => ...,
  :storage => :s3,
  :bucket => ENV['S3_BUCKET'], 
  :s3_credentials => {
    :access_key_id => ENV['S3_KEY'],
    :secret_access_key => ENV['S3_SECRET']
  }
```

You see the environment variables `ENV['S3_BUCKET']` `ENV['S3_KEY']` and `ENV['S3_SECRET']`.

You can set these variables with respect to your app as show below

**Dev:**

```
$ heroku config:set S3_BUCKET=XXX --remote dev
$ heroku config:set S3_KEY=YYY --remote dev
$ heroku config:set S3_SECRET=ZZZ --remote dev
```

**Production:**

```
$ heroku config:set S3_BUCKET=XXX --remote production
$ heroku config:set S3_KEY=YYY --remote production
$ heroku config:set S3_SECRET=ZZZ --remote production
```

**Staging:**

```
$ heroku config:set S3_BUCKET=XXX --remote staging
$ heroku config:set S3_KEY=YYY --remote staging
$ heroku config:set S3_SECRET=ZZZ --remote staging
```

Hope this answer helps somebody :-)